# Messagebird SMS webhook - confusing?

Tags: sms, iot, messagebird

I am evaluating MB I am not impressed with the support - who have not yet replied - so I am going to ask the question here.

My issues is logically very simple.  I have a simple IOT device that uses SMS to receive commands and replies with a ststus.  The backend is oracle based so using APEX / ORDS.

The send is ok.

For the reply part, I have followed the doc exactly and created an endpoint that expects a POST as defined in the API SMS doc "Receive and handle Inbound SMS":

https://developers.messagebird.com/api/sms-messaging/#receive-and-handle-inbound-sms

I have tested the service with Google ARC and it seems fine.  Returns 200 and creates the record on the DB.

However, it is not at all clear where in my account on messagebird I need to place this webhook.  The only option seems to be the "Flow Builder" and when I use the recommended template - Call HTTP endpoint with SMS, it is not possible to pass the parameters as defined in the API. (You cannot add you own parameters) and when I try other templates I canot get it to work.

So the question is please, can someone tell be ow to get this webhook working?  It seems so trivial but I just cannot seem to get it to work

I will be looking at other provider over the weekend because of the confusing layout and lack of support at MB.

Thank you
PJ

Comment: Its so disappointing that Messagebird will not answer these and other questions on here.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation seems to be out of date.
I guess the most accurate would be this article https://developers.messagebird.com/docs/sms-messaging/handle-inbound-sms/

As for what parameters are accessible in the "Call HTTP endpoint with SMS" flow, these seem to be:

- sender: the number from which the message was sent
- recipient: the number that received the message
- incoming message: the body(text) of the message

[image]